# Azure VM: More than one Public IP

Tags: azure

Can anyone confirm if Azure VM allows more than one Public IP? We want to host multiple website on single VM and hence want to have different IP for each website. I know we can host more VM, but that will greatly increase our expense too. So, I just want more than 1 Public IP on VM.

Comment: Leaving a backlink here to an [Azure UserVoice request](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking-dns-traffic-manager-vpn-vnet/suggestions/3020498-enable-the-feature-to-have-multiple-public-ip-addr) on this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you can now have multiple public IPs for a load balanced cloud service:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/multiple-vips-per-cloud-service/

> Now you can assign more than one load-balanced public IP address to a
>   set of virtual machines, enabling high-availability and high-scale
>   scenarios. You can host multiple secure websites in a cloud service or
>   allow multiple SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group listeners to
>   access the same set of virtual machines.
>
> For more information, please vistit the Load Balancer page. There is
>   no additional charge for this feature.

Answer (score 6):

You can add multiple IP addresses for a cloud service. Since the VM's are "inside" the cloud service, this gives you in a way multiple public IP addresses for a virtual machine. The procedure is documented at [1]. Additional addresses currently cost about $3/month.

Here's the steps to add a new reserved IP address to a cloud service.

First create a new reserved IP address:

```
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName "MyIPAddress"  –Location "West Europe"
```

Associate the IP address with cloud service:

```
Add-AzureVirtualIP -VirtualIPName MyIPAddress -ServiceName MyCloudService
```

Create endpoint that maps the IP address to a virtual machines. If you have multiple vm's and want load balancer, repeat this for each vm. In order to run multiple web sites, you would put each website to different port (the localport). The endpoint listens for connections on the public port and forwards them to the virtual machine's localport.

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName MyCloudService -Name myserver `
| Add-AzureEndpoint -Name QuvastoMail -Protocol tcp `
      -LocalPort 8002 -PublicPort 80 -VirtualIPName MyIPAddress `
| Update-AzureVM
```

[1] http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/

Answer (score 1):

You would need a different Cloud Service (either Web Role or Virtual Machine) to have different IP addresses.  Yes, this will increase overall cost.

The VIP (public IP) for Windows Azure Web Roles and VMs is assigned at the Cloud Service level.  Think of a Cloud Service as a logical container - it can contain web/worker roles or VMs (not both currently).

Answer (score 1):

Very possible, very easy actually.

1. Have your apps listening at your Azure Resource Managed VM, let's say ports 3001, 3002, 3003..
2. Then create an Load Balancer (just search it).
3. Create a Public IP Address.
4. Add it at your Load Balancer's Front-end Pool
5. Add your VM to your Load Balancer's Back-end Pool
6. at Inbound NAT rules of your Load Balancer, click "Add"
7. Select your frontend IP, your VM's network IP configuration, protocol, port and mapped port (click "Custom") to set a custom port.

Sample:
- You want your newly created public ip "52.165.147.25" to route to your vm's port 3001.
- On config that will be port 80 tcp, then port 3001 on mapped port.
- No need to enable "Floating IP (direct server return)" in case you see it.

PS:
On linux VM's you might have to "Optimize Your Network Kernel Parameters"..

Check here (scroll at bottom): http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/before-install

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

## Add these entries:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10240    65535
```

## Note the spaces, crucial.

## Save it.

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

## Done.

## EDIT:

### On the above steps you might have to also take care of CORS (Just google it)

### Also, Another alternative I forgot to mention is to add NIC's / Network Interfaces to ya VM's. That won't be a viable option though because of azure max-nic-per-vm limits.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the earlier answer about Cloud Services, it is now possible to have multiple IP addresses on an Azure VM.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one public IP address per deployment. So if you had 3 VMs in a single deployment, they'd share IP address. You can then choose to load-balance traffic across the instances or direct traffic to a particular VM (or role in cloud services) for a specific port number.

You can use host headers and support multiple websites in a single VM.

Comment: I know about Host Headers, but due to some business restriction we do not want to have both site use same IP. Reading your answer, it seems we have not choice but to opt for different VM. However can you explain what you mean by "Single Deployment" We use Azure Portal to create VM, so creating second machine will be second deployment or same?

Comment: A single deployment can have several roles... e.g. a webrole and 2 worker roles - but it's only one deployment package. Each role have at least one VM - depending on instance count. If instance count is 2 you pay for 6 VMs.

Answer (score -2):

We are also having similar problems. We wanted to have multiple SSL certificates applied to multiple sites hosted withing Virtual Machine.

but it seems its not possible at all. Waiting for MS to release this feature.

Comparatively Godaddy and other hosting providers give free 2-3 IP addressed as well if you need more you can request additional Ip Address easily.

as well to get hold of support is too much difficult.

MZ azure really sucks. :(

Comment: funny you mention godaddy. I agree they give lot of IP, but they really are not comparable when it comes to speed of server. Azure server are lot more faster and reliable than godaddy, I have 3 godaddy server and about 2 azure server and hence know the difference.

Comment: Yes, i agree with sumit, godaddy VPS servers are not as powerful as azure.

Comment: Godaddy is horrible when compared with Azure.