# multiple public IPs for Azure Virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I have found it difficult to figure out how to have multiple public IPs for one Azure Virtual Server...

1. it is possible?
2. exactly what are the commands to do so?

I've already added what seemed to be virtual ips via [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132756/azure-vm-more-than-one-public-ip). which also references [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/multiple-vips-per-cloud-service/)

But I'm really confused now...
[This link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/) talks about pricing pricing pricing, but nowhere on any page so far have I seen how to actually ***configure*** a load balancer..
There's a difference between ReservedIPs and Virtual IPs(VIPs)...

help?

Comment: I believe you are more interested on adding additional public IP on VM level and NOT on cloud service level. Let me know if I am getting you wrong.

Comment: I don't really understand the difference so... the answer is, yes, I need multiple public IPs however it has to happen in order to have multiple sites on their own public IP each in order to have SSL certs for each. Thanks.

Comment: Then in that case the answer already posted by me will surely help you...

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. When an Azure VM is created, it automatically gets a public ip which you can see on the portal or by using powershell command-

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "testservice" -Name "testvm" | select PublicIPAddress
```

However in order to add one more additional public IP only poweshell can help you (NOT possible using portal). This provides an additional IP at VM level and NOT at cloud service level.Command-

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "testservice" -Name "testvm"-app-1 | Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName "testpublicIP"| Update-AzureVM
```

Here is the link for your reference- http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/10/28/step-by-step-assign-a-public-ip-to-a-vm-in-azure.aspx

Comment: I have added VIPs.. but now the missing piece is, how to assign extra local IPs to the virtual machine and link the VIPs to each individual local IP respectively. So, in IIS Mgr, I have more than 'All Unassigned' and the one local IP. I need that to happen in order to assign separate SSL certs to each site.

Comment: I wound up using this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/ but it's forwarding additional ports differently since there's still only one internal IP... it's working for now, but it's a sloppy compromise. Particularly the "How to associate a VIP to an endpoint" part.